# Where clauses in linq .Includes

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following statement:

```
var field = _context.Set<Field>().FromSql($@"SELECT Id, F1, F2, F3
                            FROM Table1")
            .Include(model => model.Table2)
            .Include(model => model.Table2.Table3);

        return PartialView("_IndexGrid", field.ToList());
```

I want to add where clauses to that, so that a single given search string can be applied to all three entities.  For instance, if I have a variable named **search** I'd like to have Table1, Table2 and Table3 all filtered on **search**.  Each Table will be applying the filter on a different field name. 
 How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do sometihng like this?

```
var field = _context.Set<Field>().FromSql($@"SELECT Id, F1, F2, F3
                            FROM Table1")
                        .Include(model => model.Table2)
                        .Include(model => model.Table2.Table3)
                        .Select(g => new Field {
                            Foo = g.Stuff,
                            Bar = g.Thing,
                            Baz = g.Table2.Where(t => t.MyName.Equals(search)),
                            Feh = g.Table2.Table3.Where(t => !t.YourName.Equals(search))
                        });
```